# PHP - ssh2_exec and stream_select( ) error

Tags: php, python

When I try to use `ssh2_exec` to run a python script on a remote server, and try to make it running under un-blocking model. An error shows up:

> stream_select(): cannot represent a stream of type SSH2 Channel as a
>   select()able descriptor

**My code:**

```
$ssh_connection = ssh2_connect('server ip address',22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh_connection, 'root', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh_connection, 'cd /opt/; python db.py'); 

stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$read = array($stream);
$write = array();
$except = array();

$return_string = stream_get_contents($stream); 

//echo $return_string;

stream_select($read, $write, $except, 300);
```

Does anybody know why it shows me that error?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are you dont have acces or banned on remote server. Try to run from another IP.